# iOS : Programmatically call onTapGesture from another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I currently have a UIView, call it (A), that is outsourced out into a 3rd party library.
Pressing onTapGesture physically would be simple, but the problem here is that this (A) is on another view hierarchy, versus the one I have. The reason for this is that I apply transforms to this separate from (A).

Im deciding on delegating a UIButton that will programmatically call the UIView in question's onTapGesture, is there a way to do this?

I do not have access to this 3rd party library's selector for onTap.

Comment: are you saying this third party library has a view that you can't access the on tap function that it calls?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, unless you of Unity's onTap call in its library...

Comment: if you are using unity,  why are you doing stuff in Xcode?

Comment: I'm using it's view, and I need a view on top of it that requires transforms. I also want to delegate and use its ontap calls. This works if its in the same view heirarchy as the view with transforms, but doesn't play to nice when it itself is transforming

Comment: yeah, you may have better luck changing your topic to reflect you are using a view from Unity

Comment: Agreed, but I want to generalize it as this could be another 3rd party library as well, and its UI front end is native. No matter the case, I did find a work around which involved disabling user interaction on the first screen to allow delegation of on top to the next. So when you have onTap, it will go onto the next view over.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer to your question. If you still working on this may be my answer will be helpful or may be someone else will find it helpful.

The gesture doesn't expose its target and action. In this case may be creating a fake touch programatically will be helpful. As you have `UIView` you can easily get the `window` of that view. With window find out the x,y co-ordinate and create a fake `UITouch` event. I also had similar kind of problem and creating fake touch worked for me. [This](http://blog.lazerwalker.com/objective-c/code/2013/10/16/faking-touch-events-on-ios-for-fun-and-profit.html) is the link I referred for creating fake touches.